# How do you parse this date format in java?

Tags: java, datetime

Simple question: what format should I use with this date?

```
2011-10-09T05:06:03.000000Z
```

This one does not work:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ"
```

From the manual: "The timestamp is calculated from epoch_ticks (zulu), format=%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"

Comment: What is that last set of zeroes? Milliseconds? Timezone offset?

Comment: @sjr java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011-11-23T21:59:00.000000Z"

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas have no idea, it is not something I created. It is a public dataset I am processing.

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'", the Z is for Zulu (UTC) probably.

Comment: Yes, it is zulu, this is what i found:  "The timestamp is calculated from epoch_ticks (zulu), format=%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ",

Comment: That is *standard* ISO-8601 in full-form (it can have up to 6 digits of fractional second precision). Nothing special.

Comment: Seems like there is another SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is "you can't".  For some reason Java does not support "Z" as a time zone identifier.  You can do a workaround like this though:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date d = df.parse("2011-10-09T05:06:03.000000Z");
```

This assumes that the date will be in UTC and ignores the Z.